# Submit a form with jquery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, forms, submit

I have a form:

```
<form action="thanks.php" onsubmit="return false" class="submitForm">
... Some Inputs ...
</form>
```

and a jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("form.submitForm").on("submit", function() {
        $("form.submitForm").attr("onsubmit", "return true");
        $("form.submitForm").submit;
    });
});
```

Now I like to submit the form with the jQuery Code. It works, BUT only at the second enter or submit...
I don't understand why it doesn't work...

Thanks for any help!

Sorry for my english mistakes, I'm from Germany.

Comment: Adding a `return false;` at the end will prevent default submit behaviour, if that's what you want, and I believe `.submit;` needs to be `.submit();`

Comment: Before it worked with `.submit;`.
I tried
`$("form.submitForm").on("submit", function() {
  $("form.submitForm").attr("onsubmit", "return true");
  $("form.submitForm").submit;
                return false;
 });` but it doesn't work...

Is it possible that the attribute "onsubmit" doesn't have the value "return true" in the DOM after the first submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why it doesn't submit :**

Your form doesnt submit because you have the `onsubmit` attribute to `return false`. That is preventing the form from submiting, which is probably what you want since you try to resubmit it with `$("form.submitForm").submit;`. Unfortunnatly, this will not work since you need to add brackets like that : `$("form.submitForm").submit();`

**Why it submit the second time :**

On the first submit, you are preventing the default behavior (`return false`), but you are changing the `onsubmit` attribute to `return true`. That will remove the default prevention you had at first.

So overall, you clikc the first time, prevent default behavior with `return false`, doesnt submit because there is a misstake in `$("form.submitForm").submit;` and then change the `return false` to true, removing what was preventing the form from submitting.

**Solution :**

Use this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form.submitForm").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $("form.submitForm").submit();
    });
});
```

But if you have nothing else in that code, why brother preventdefault and then do the default behavior?

Comment: Later I add some validate functions :)